# Idea for proof that this $\Sigma$-formula holds in every nonempty structure

Tags: logic

Can someone give me a hint, how to prove that the $\Sigma$-formula

$$ \neg (\psi_{x \rightarrow t} \ \& \ \exists x \psi)$$

where $\psi$ is an arbitrary  $\Sigma$-formula, $t$ is a  $\Sigma$-term whose variable don't appear in $\psi$ and $x$ is any variable, holds in every nonempty structure ?

(What "$\psi_{x \rightarrow t}$" means and for other technical details, over which alphabet the $\Sigma$-terms etc. were defined see a different [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47369/which-strings-are-in-this-set) of mine)

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? The assertion you are asking us to prove is false. If $\psi$ is a tautology, for example, with no free variables, then $\psi$ and $\exists x\ \psi$ hold in every structure.

Comment: Yes, you were right. joriki figured in his answer out what I meant. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JDH pointed out, this is false. I'll assume that you meant

$$\neg (\psi_{x \rightarrow t} \ \& \ \neg\exists x \psi)$$

(with a negation added).

If $x$ does not occur in $\psi$, then the formula holds in every nonempty structure since in this case the replacement and the existential quantifier are irrelevant (since there exists at least one $x$ in the nonempty structure), so the formula holds iff $\neg(\psi\&\neg\psi)$ holds.

If $x$ does occur in $\psi$, then for the first conjunct to be true $t$ has to evaluate to an $x$ that makes $\psi$ true, and hence $\exists x\psi$, so in this case the second conjunct is false.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. thanks.